# Gravitational wave for Solo mass system

Tags: gravitational-waves

every equation i found in internet for gravitational wave radiation is for binary system which is need 2 mass in order to find strain (h).

my question is:
if we have one mass which is oscillate , how about this one for calculating strain(h) ?

for example: for a single mass 1.000.000 kg & frequency 100 times per second

if there is formula or reference link , let us know.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrupole_formula has the relevant equations. But the configuration of your oscillator is unclear. Is it just moving back & forth on a line? How far does it travel on each oscillation? The calculations for binary systems assume that the centre of mass doesn't move, but that's not the case for your oscillator.

Comment: Define what you mean by a single source and how its mass distribution oscillates.

Comment: @PM2Ring 1-what is 'r' in that formula? 2-i can put kg mass in 'I' in the formula?  3-frequency is not important? 4-this formula give us strain?

Comment: @ProfRob suppose that i have a ball in my hand shake it in different frequency. the single mass is constant(for example 1.000.000 kg) but frequency may differ in any moment. how can i solve and calculate Strain in any moment.

Comment: The formula is given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrupole_formula . If you don't understand that formula then I suggest you reformulate your question to ask about that.

Comment: Note that you have to conserve momentum, so if you're pushing a mass back and forth, you also have to account for the motion of yourself pushing it. This is basically why gravitational waves are sourced by time-varying mass quadrupoles. Time-varying mass dipoles are not even allowed.

Comment: @ProfRob no i do not meant move through a line , shake it with momentum. in your link above , i do not see frequency of that mass?  there must be mass and frequency as an input in formula in order to find strain (h).

Comment: @Sten yes , with momentum , mass and frequency as an input in formula in order to find strain (h). how can i solve it? or if you can send it as an example pf solving with virtual mass and frequency as a thought experiment

Comment: If you want an object to swing around a point of equilibrium, you need a restoring force. Who or what does this when there is no second body anywhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose you have a mass $m$ moving up and down along the z-axis according to:

$$ z(t) = A \cos\omega t $$

The traceless part of the quadrople moment tensor then has components

\begin{align}
I_{xx}^T &= -\frac{1}{3} m A^2 \cos^2\omega t,\\
I_{yy}^T &= -\frac{1}{3} m A^2 \cos^2\omega t,\\
I_{zz}^T &= \frac{2}{3} m A^2 \cos^2\omega t,\\
\end{align}

with all other components zero.

This can be plugged into [quadrupole formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrupole_formula):

$$ \bar{h}_{ij}(t,r) = \frac{2 G}{c^4 r} \ddot{I}_{ij}(t-r/c)$$

to find the spatial part of the trace reversed perturbation of the metric, $\bar{h}_{ij}$.

The average power emitted in gravitational waves is
$$\frac{16G}{15c^5} A^4m^2\omega^6.$$

Note that the quadrupole formula is an approximation only valid in the non-relativistic approximation, i.e. $A\omega\ll c.$

Suppose I am waving my hand up and down, and want to know the gravitational waves produced. For sake of simplicity we put $m = 1 kg$, $A=1 m$, and $\omega = 1Hz$, the emitted power is then about $1.5\times10^{-52} W$. That is very small. To see how small, lets suppose that gravity is in fact quantized. The energy of a single quantum (i.e. graviton) should then be $\hbar\omega\approx 1\times10^{-34} J$. So, I'd expect to emitted less then one graviton per [Hubble time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble%27s_law#Hubble_time). So while you might sometimes see a gravitational wave physicist on stage claim that wave their hands about would generate gravitational waves, this might not quite be true due to quantum effects!

Comment: thanks a zillion !!! really good answer. can you calculate strain (h) also so that i can see how formula works for that? for your aboved example

Comment: also what is A ? you meant in 1 square meter deposit???

Comment: A is the amplitude of the oscillation.

Comment: can also caculate strain (h) for your example ? thanks

Comment: I can, but so can you. Everything you need is here.

Comment: i do not know what is 'r'  and what is 't' in that formula

Comment: after calculate each component, i must sum ix,iy, iz together in order to place in strain fromula.?